# Nginx dosen't detectes root symlink changes

Tags: nginx

When deploying with capifony, Nginx dosen't detectes root symlink changes. I am restarting the nginx then it works. how configure to work it on the fly.

Comment: Nginx doesn't detect changes once it is started. You need to reload it instead of restarting. a simple `nginx -s reload` can do the job

Comment: Yes, nginx don't detects it

Comment: I am not sure what could be the cause because I use symlinks with nginx and it works for me

Comment: problem is not in symlink reading. problem in changing the directory with the some symlink. Capifony does it to save versioning of application.

Comment: are your configs using relative paths by any chance? Inside the config i mean

Comment: See, nginx linked ot "current" folder, but the real path is changing in deployment process.

`
├── current -> /var/www/my_app_name/releases/20150120114500/
├── releases
│   ├── 20150080072500
│   ├── 20150090083000
│   ├── 20150100093500
│   ├── 20150110104000
│   └── 20150120114500├── repo
│   └── <VCS related data>
├── revisions.log
└── shared
    └── <linked_files and linked_dirs>

`

Comment: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure/

Comment: The app which nginx proxy is what? Ruby app ? Python app? What is the actual backend here?

Comment: Capistrano is only deployment tool. you can deploy anything from HTMLs to PHP or Node

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167509/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-createit-am).